# Search filter in multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, search, filter

How would I create a search function that search in multidimensional nested array?

Given the following array :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [parent_name] => ACTIVITIES
        [children] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [parent_name] => ANIMALS/PETS
        [children] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [parent_name] => ART
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [post_id] => 100
                        [child_name] => Bookeeping
                        [painting] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => flower
                                [1] => beach
                                [2] => sunrise
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [post_id] => 101
                        [child_name] => Addiction
                        [painting] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => sunrise
                                [1] => beach
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [parent_name] => Music
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [post_id] => 102
                        [child_name] => POP
                        [painting] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => suntown
                                [1] => beachfull
                                [2] => sunrise
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [post_id] => 103
                        [child_name] => Rock
                        [painting] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => sunrisenew
                                [1] => beachnew
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
)
```

How would I filter this array with a key which search in 'painting'?

For example search key is "sun"

Result should be like this :

```
Array
(

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [parent_name] => ART
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [post_id] => 100
                        [child_name] => Bookeeping
                        [painting] => Array
                            (
                                [2] => sunrise
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [post_id] => 101
                        [child_name] => Addiction
                        [painting] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => sunrise
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [parent_name] => Music
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [post_id] => 102
                        [child_name] => POP
                        [painting] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => suntown
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [post_id] => 103
                        [child_name] => Rock
                        [painting] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => sunrisenew
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
)
```

Comment: Did you consider array_filter() with a callback? Does it have to preserve the root keys in the array(2 and 3 in your example output)?

Comment: No preserving array key is not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$needle = "sun";
$filteredArr = array_filter(
    $arr,
    function($v) use ($needle) {
        foreach($v['children'] as $child) {
            // "Version 1" of filtering, no "parts of strings" searches
            if (in_array($needle, $child['painting'])) {
                return true;
            }

            // "Version 2" of filtering, keyword may be part of a painting string
            foreach($child['painting'] as $painting) {
                if (strpos($painting, $needle) !== false) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
);
```

If you use the callback for array_filter() then you can do fairly advanced filterings.

**Edit**
New version of answer for removing the entries in painting arrays not matching the pattern.

This works by doing nested foreach loops, all the way in to the innermost array needed, *painting* in this case.
The *painting* array is filtered so that all non matching elements in it are removed.
When done with this, at the next level outwards, the *painting* array is checked, and if empty the removal kind of "propagates outwards". This way only the entries with matching painting entries should be left, and it should be sort of scalable.

The references aren't strictly necessary, one could add array key variables to the foreach loops instead. But I didn't like all the indexing this caused.

```
$needle = 'sun';

foreach($arr as $entryKey => &$entry) {
    foreach($entry['children'] as $childKey => &$child) {
        foreach($child['painting'] as $paintingKey => $painting) {
            if (strpos($painting, $needle) === false) {
                unset($child['painting'][$paintingKey]);
            }
        }

        if (empty($child['painting'])) {
            unset($entry['children'][$childKey]);
        }
    }

    if (empty($entry['children'])) {
        unset($arr[$entryKey]);
    }
}
unset($entry, $child); // Take no risks with references
```

Comment: Didn't read the question too closely, but isn't that `return false` statement at the wrong place? The first `foreach` won't ever iterate this way.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo It gives the main array which haves the needle but its not filtering the painting array.

Comment: @BhaveyBansal Oh? So the painting arrays in the result should only contain the matching entries? I missed that part.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo Yes, painting array should contain only matching result but upper arrays should not be changed.Preserving keys is not important.

Comment: @BhaveyBansal Apologies for the delay, added new version of answer. Array keys _are_ preserved now. Adding calls to array_values() should fix this if needed.